# Github actions scp-action failing

Tags: github, github-actions

I have been using github actions in one of my project for last 2 months to deploy to my QA environment using `appleboy/scp-action`. So far it was working fine.

But for last 3 days the action is consistently giving following error:

```
tar all files into /tmp/762144744/PmqnH47N72.tar
scp file to server.
drone-scp error:  error copy file to dest: ***, error message: dial tcp ***:***: i/o timeout
2020/04/02 03:12:52 error copy file to dest: ***, error message: dial tcp ***:***: i/o timeout
```

I have tried using the `timeout`to increase it as per the documentation, but no use. Any guess???

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: hi could you resolve this?

Comment: I couldn't, I shifted to self hosted, so I didn't had to use the scp. I believe git action is yet not reliable. Even with self hosted I faced other issues like test or build getting stuck & issue with other actions. Fun part is most of the time the problem occured when I needed git action the most :)

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am having the same problem too

Answer (score 0):

For me, it seems to be related to 2 things:

1. Caching of npm dependencies
2. Wrong permissions on folder. So, I gave the write access.

Now it's fine, but it seems not really fiable.

Answer (score -2):

Please check your storage of os.
If you are using linux OS then you can use it.

```
df -h
```

And you may be increase storage or remove some unnecessary files.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30781250)